# How to download excel file from a specific website by clicking a button and using Python?

Tags: python, file, automation, download

The link in question is

https://www.de.vanguard/professionell/produktart/etf/aktien/9505/ftse-all-world-ucits-etf-usd-distributing#portfoliodaten

Currently I click manually the marked button in yellow shown in the screenshot. How can I instead use Python **downloading the file** into a **specific folder** and **rename** it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Selenium. After setting up your driver;

Right click on the button, inspect. Copy full xpath.

```
driver.get("https://www.de.vanguard/professionell/produktart/etf/aktien/9505/ftse-all-world-ucits-etf-usd-distributing#portfoliodaten")

dlbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/europe-core-root/europe-core-global-nav/div/europe-core-product-detail-page-component/section[4]/europe-core-market-allocation-container/europe-core-market-allocation/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/europe-core-download-button/button/span")

dlbutton.click()
```

Comment: Ty, is there another way to download the file without using Selenium and a way, where I can download into a specific folder?

Comment: You can also download using "request".  
To download in to a certain folder, just change the working directory before download. I'm assuming you just want to download a single file :)

Comment: ty. :) helped me a lot.